# How do I access Spring properties in a logback configuration

Tags: spring, logback

Is there a way to access Spring properties within a logback.xml file?

I know one can import a properties file if you know its location, but I'm using Spring profiles to control where the properties file should be loaded or not.

Is there done kind of connector that asked me to feed Spring data into logback? This would only be at startup; I don't need to be able to do this on the fly.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of properties you need from spring and how its set in logback.xml

Comment: Are you using `spring-boot`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you do have to import a property file (common property file, non-environment specific one) that will contain the name of the property that you are going to use in the logback.xml, and that you want to *optionally* override the value of the property for some environment (you need at least one property file containing the name of the property, because you will be using that property in the logback.xml, and you need it to be available to be able to use it).

For the optional environment-override, how about including an additional property file? For example, we use both `application.properties` and `application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties` files. Then if we *don't* need to override the property for some environment, we simply *don't* include it in the environment specific property file (`application-dev.properties`, etc.)